# Connecting Jetbrains DataGrip to a remote database via SSH

Tags: mysql, ssh, amazon-lightsail

I have an AWS Lightsail instance running the Bitnami configuration for Ubuntu 16.04.5 LTS and PHP7.

I can connect the the MySQL database using phpMyAdmin on the server via an SSH Tunnel.  But when I try to configure DataGrip for SSH access to the database I receive the error message "Host '127.0.0.1' is not allowed to connect to this MySQL server".

When I remove "localhost" from the host field of the General tab then I receive the error "ExecutionException: SSH: Unable to find host/port in URL".

The following test and response appears to show a successful connection to the port:

```
cat < /dev/tcp/###.###.###.###/22
SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_7.2p2 Ubuntu-4ubuntu2.6
```

I'm using keypair auth. Both the user name and the Private key file are the same used for the ssh tunnel when running phpMyAdmin.

Not sure what to try next.  Any help appreciated.